# Роль от роли Rbac Yii

Tags: yii2

Подскажите и покажите на примере, как правильно унаследовать роль от роли в Rbac DbManager .  Yii2.
Условие: имеютс глобальные роли (админ, юзер)
Хочу разделить админ на (генеральный, модератор)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$auth = \Yii::$app->authManager;
$admin = $auth->getRole('admin');

$general = $auth->createRole('general');
$moder = $auth->createRole('moder');

$auth->addChild($admin, $general);
$auth->addChild($admin, $moder);
```